Updating the URI based on the previous URI
In my React application, I do multiple updates of the URI (by adding query parameters) within the same event with the router.push function from multiple locations in the code. The issue is that some updates are lost because updates are not based on the previous URI.
Here is a minimal working example to illustrate the issue:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    router.push({
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, x: 'foo' },
    });
    router.push({
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, y: 'bar' },
    });
    router.push({
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, z: 'baz' },
    });
  }, [router.pathname, router.query.x, router.query.y, router.query.z]);
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(router.query).map(([key, value]) => (
        <li key={key}>
          {key}: {value}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

It renders


x: foo
z: baz


instead of


x: foo
y: bar
z: baz


If router.push accepted updater functions like the set function returned by the useState hook, the issue would be elegantly solved:
router.push((prevUrl) => ({
  pathname: prevUrl.pathname,
  query: { ...prevUrl.query, x: 'foo' },
}));
router.push((prevUrl) => ({
  pathname: prevUrl.pathname,
  query: { ...prevUrl.query, y: 'bar' },
}));
router.push((prevUrl) => ({
  pathname: prevUrl.pathname,
  query: { ...prevUrl.query, z: 'baz' },
}));

Is there an alternative solution?

A solution is, instead of doing multiple URI updates, to introduce component state and do multiple state updates and a single URI update:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [x, setX] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [y, setY] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [z, setZ] = useState<string | undefined>();
  useEffect(() => {
    setX('foo');
    setY('bar');
    setZ('baz');
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    router.push({
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, x, y, z},
    });
  }, [router.pathname, router.query.x, router.query.y, router.query.z]);
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(router.query).map(([key, value]) => (
        <li key={key}>
          {key}: {value}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

